# How to render <google-chart> web component in Polymer

Tags: google-visualization, polymer, yeoman, web-component, html-imports

**NOTE: UPDATES (including solution) to this question at the end...**

I can't get a `<google-chart>` element to render on my page.

I used Yeoman's Polymer generator to scaffold a Polymer project. I have added some custom elements and also imported and instantiated Iron and Paper elements from the [Polymer Catalog](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse). I am using the standard procedure to do this:

1. `bower install --save [[polymerElement]]`, then
2. `<link rel="import" href="../bower.../[[element]].html">` in `elements.html`.

Following the [`<google-chart>` instructions](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart) in the [Google Web Components catalog section](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=google-web-components), I have tried to render their example pie chart on my page. Although the element isn't rendering correctly, there are no errors in the console, there is a gap in the page content for the element, and the markup all appears in my inspector, with 2 exceptions:

1. The rendered HTML does not include a "rows" attribute, which I cannot seem to fix.
2. The inner content of the `<google-chart>` component is rather sparse, with just 3 children elements:

   - `<iron-ajax>`
   - `<div>`
   - `<google-legacy-loader>`

Here is the relevant code:

**elements.html:**

```
<!-- Iron elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-component-page/iron-component-page.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/maps-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/social-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">

<!-- Paper elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles-classes.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">

<!-- 3rd Party Components -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-apis/google-apis.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-apis/google-js-api.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-chart/google-chart.html">

<!-- etc... -->
```

**index.html:**

```
<section data-route="dashboard">
    <h2 class="page-title">Data Dashboard</h2>
    <p>This is the dashboard section</p>
    <p>This is a 'google-chart' object:</p>
    <google-chart type='pie' options='{"title": "Distribution of days in 2001Q1"}' rows='[["Jan", 31], ["Feb", 28], ["Mar", 31]]' cols='[{"label":"Month", "type":"string"}, {"label":"Days", "type":"number"}]'></google-chart>

    <p>You can get more info here:</p>
    <a href="https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart">https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart</a>
</section>
<!-- etc... -->
```

---

**UPDATE:**

As [Supersharp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4600982/supersharp) stated, this `<google-charts>` code loads in a single page environment.

As far as loading in the Yeoman-scaffolded Polymer environment I'm working in, after further testing it seems that the `<google-chart>` object **will** load in the main `app/index.html` file **as long as** it is **not** in the `<template>` tag:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    ...
    <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild-->

    <!-- build:js bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- will be replaced with elements/elements.vulcanized.html -->
    <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">
    <!-- endreplace-->

    <!-- For shared styles, shared-styles.html import in elements.html -->
    <style is="custom-style" include="shared-styles"></style>
</head>

<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">
    <span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>

NOTE: google-chart will load here...

    <template is="dom-bind" id="app">

NOTE: google-chart WON'T load here or in any of the elements below...

        <paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel">
            <!-- Drawer Scroll Header Panel -->
            <paper-scroll-header-panel drawer>
                <!-- Drawer Toolbar -->
                <paper-toolbar id="drawerToolbar"> ... </paper-toolbar>
                <!-- Nav Menu Section Title -->
                <paper-item class="menu-section-title"> ... </paper-item>
                <!-- Drawer Section Content -->
                <paper-menu class="list" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]"> ... </paper-menu>
            </paper-scroll-header-panel>
            <!-- Main Area -->
            <paper-scroll-header-panel main condenses keep-condensed-header>
                <!-- Main Toolbar -->
                <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar" class="tall" alt-class="medium-tall"> ... </paper-toolbar>
                <!-- Main Content -->
                <div class="content"> ... </div>
            </paper-scroll-header-panel>
        </paper-drawer-panel>
    </template>

NOTE: google-chart will load here...

    <!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
    <script src="scripts/userData.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild-->
</body>
</html>
```

However, I need the `<google-charts>` component loaded in that `<template>` block (where all the rest of the content is).

Can anyone explain why this won't load in the `<template>` block?

Can anyone further explain how I can get this element to render wherever I want it in the app?

Thank you all so much in advance.

---

**SOLUTION:**

Using the [Registration and Lifecycle Callbacks](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#initialization-order) I have successfully rendered this in a template with the following method:

First, add a queryable element into the `<template>` element to serve as a container:

```
<p>This is a 'google-chart' object:</p>
<figure id="chart-container"></figure>
```

Second, inside the `Polymer()` constructor, create the `<google-chart>` element and attach it to the container as part of the `attached` lifecycle event:

```
attached: function() {
  // create an instance with createElement:
  var chartContainer = document.querySelector('figure#chart-container');

  var pieChartAttributes = {
    'id': 'pie-chart',
    'type': 'pie',
    'options': '{"title": "Distribution of days in 2001Q1"}',
    'rows': '[["Jan", 31], ["Feb", 28], ["Mar", 31]]',
    'cols': '[{"label":"Month", "type":"string"}, {"label":"Days", "type":"number"}]',
  };

  var pieChart = document.createElement('google-chart');

  for (var key in pieChartAttributes) {
    pieChart.setAttribute(key, pieChartAttributes[key]);
  }

  chartContainer.appendChild(pieChart);
} // end attached()
```

While there is a slight delay in the element rendering on-screen, this is a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've copy-pasted your code and in a single file and it worked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="import" href="/scripts/components/google-chart/google-chart.html">
</head>
<body>
    <section data-route="dashboard">
        <h2 class="page-title">Data Dashboard</h2>
        <p>This is the dashboard section</p>
        <p>This is a 'google-chart' object:</p>
        <google-chart type='pie' options='{"title": "Distribution of days in 2001Q1"}' rows='[["Jan", 31], ["Feb", 28], ["Mar", 31]]' cols='[{"label":"Month", "type":"string"}, {"label":"Days", "type":"number"}]'></google-chart>

        <p>You can get more info here:</p>
        <a href="https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart">https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart</a>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

NB: Only the custom element you explicitely use (*ie* `google-chart`) should be imported as a `<link>`.

**UPDATE**

[`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) content is never rendered. It's the main purpose of that type of element. You'll have to copy its content to another element (not a `template`!) in the main `document` to make it visible. The other nested elements won't render more.
Example [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/).

Comment: Thanks for testing this - I can duplicate your results. The chart loads in a single file. I've updated my question with the new information I've learned.

Comment: Thanks again so much - however, I don't fully understand your update. Let me try:

I think you're saying that I can't nest `<link rel="import">` tags -- as in, my main document is importing the `elements.html` file, so I can't have additional imports specified in that file. That would be a nested import.

My confusion here is that this is the explicit pattern not only in the scaffold (which has working nested imports all over), but also in the `bower_components` web component files. They regularly include imports, and I'm importing them (like google-charts.html).

Where am I confused?

Comment: What I call nested `<link>` are the links inside `elements.html`. Because `elements.html` is *itself* imported by a `<link>` in the main document `index.html`. So every file referenced by `<link rel=import>` inside the `element.html` imported document won't be imported automatically.

Comment: Thank you - this got me to an answer. The key was not adding it into the <template> block. I've updated my question with my working solution.

Answer (score 4):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738459/polymer-1-0-is-there-any-ready-made-chart-element):

insert blanks in

```
'rows': '[ ["Jan", 31], ["Feb", 28], ["Mar", 31] ]',
```

instead of

```
'rows': '[["Jan", 31], ["Feb", 28], ["Mar", 31]]',
```

because inside the template [[ ]] is recognized for one way data binding.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. I think this should be the accepted answer.